# API Creation Inquiry

Tags: java, api, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a project that needs an API. In most APIs (for example Minecraft Modloader), the API runs the "mod" class, without knowing its name. How is this possible? For this project, I need to get all instances of a class called Spell, without ever calling them directly. All tips and answers are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure what forge modloader and risu's modloader do is look inside the zips and find any classes with what it needs to be considered a mod class, for example in forge, a @mod annotation. Then it will attempt to load that mod. This is actually how many mods like buildcraft have different parts of the mod in the same zip.